# Kendo grid with 100% and navigation header

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid and want to display a header with navigation elements.

Please see my example in Teleriks Dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/iWIXa

When I add the < header> element the full height functionality is broken (the pager at the bottom will be slipping down).

How is it possible to fix this issue?

Thanks
Sven

Comment: Remove the `overflow: hidden` attribute from the `html` CSS to allow scrolling so you can access the `pager`?

Comment: @Sandman Then I will get two scrollbars. This is not the intended solution. The pager should stick at the bottom of the grid and only the grid content should scroll. When removing the header everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/iWIXa/7) which does what you need. Note how the `resizeGrid()` function is called on the grid `dataBound` event aswell as during the `window.resize` event.

```
function resizeGrid() {
    var gridElement = $("#grid");
    var dataArea = gridElement.find(".k-grid-content");
    var newHeight = gridElement.parent().innerHeight() - 75; 
    var diff = gridElement.innerHeight() - dataArea.innerHeight();
    gridElement.height(newHeight);
    dataArea.height(newHeight - diff);
}
```

Notice how 75 is used, this value is what can be used to modify the size in order to bring the grid inside the boundary of the screen. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it seems to work. I thought it should be possible with the base functionality of kendo grid and/or plain css. I already knew about the resizeGrid function but sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees. Nevertheless thanks.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

So I have tweaked your code slightly [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iWIXa/8)

Using some code I actually use with my grids.

Similar to @Sandman I am reszing the grid but rather than having external styles setup on the grid I am using the `window` as the thing to determine the resize.

so the code:

```
function initializeGrid(options)
{

    if(options === null || options === undefined)
    {
        options = {
            size: 0.55,
            gridContentCss: ".k-grid-content",
            gridLockedContentCss: ".k-grid-content-locked",
            gridsToResize:[]
        };
    }


    var windowHeight = $(window).height() * options.size;

    if(options.gridsToResize !== null && options.gridsToResize.length > 0 )
    {
        options.gridsToResize.forEach(function (item) {
            var gridContent = $('#' + item + ' > ' + options.gridContentCss);


            var lockedContent = $('#' + item + ' > ' + options.gridLockedContentCss);




            gridContent.height(windowHeight);

            if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
                lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

            }
        }); 
    }
    else 
    {
        var gridContent = $(options.gridContentCss);
        var lockedContent = $(options.gridLockedContentCss);

        gridContent.height(windowHeight);

        if (lockedContent !== null && lockedContent !== undefined) {
            lockedContent.height(windowHeight);

        }
    }


}
```

So this is a more expanded solution this function takes an `options` object (if one isn't provided then a default one is created which with auto resize the grid or grids to 55% of the windows height.

In my example I have created an object here

```
 var gridOptions = {
            size: 0.70,
            gridContentCss: ".k-grid-content",
            gridLockedContentCss: ".k-grid-content-locked",
            gridsToResize:[]
        };
```

So I am telling the grid to use 70% of the height of the current window to resize.

I am also telling it to resize both locked and non-locked content as resizing can make the locked content get out of `sync` with the unlocked content.

I am also able to tell the code to only resize certain grids so if you had multiple grids on the screen you could adjust them all or just some of them. If nothing is provided the function assumes all grids will be adjusted on the screen.

Then on top of that I am just binding this function to the window resize function which will work up to a point when the default css takes over and if you shrink to say less than 420px's of screen height then scrolling is going to happen on both the window and the grid.

I have left a console statement in the code so you can see it resizing.

As I said this is a more expanded solution than Sandman's solution

Comment: Thank you David, I will try it out.